# numpy.dot выдает странные результаты

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Занимаюсь нейронками. Перешёл на питон с плюсов, вроде он лучше для сетей. Пытаюсь освоить функцию dot для перемножения весов и нейронов. Но вот не понятно. Учусь по гайду на Хабре "нейронная сеть в 11 строчек". Там на вход - двухмерный массив, в первом измерении сам пример, во втором - элементы. У меня так же. 1000 примеров и 64 элемента в каждом, это входной слой. В ответ хочу получить одномерный массив размером 44 элемента. Но dot возвращает двухмерный массив 1000х1000. Вот часть кода

```py
w0 = 2 * np.random.random((64, 120))-1
w1 = 2 * np.random.random((120, 240))-1
w2 = 2 * np.random.random((240, 240))-1
w3 = 2 * np.random.random((240, 240))-1
w4 = 2 * np.random.random((240, 120))-1
w5 = 2 * np.random.random((120, 44))-1 # веса
n0 = np.zeros((1000,64)) # первый слой с данными (потом заполняется по базе данных)
n1 = sigmoid(np.dot(n0, w0))
#...
n6 = sigmoid(np.dot(n5, w5)) #проход по сети
```

И почему-то получается размер n6 1000х1000. Почему? Как мне получить одномерный, длиной в 44 элемента?

Comment: какие размерности у переменных `n5` и `w5`?

Comment: что-то вы не договариваете. в показанном примере размерность `w5`: `(120, 44)`, следовательно число столбцов (второе число в кортеже размерности) в `n6` должно получиться `44` и никак не может быть `1000`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Массивы n2-n5 инициализируются так же как и n1 и n6. Кстати сейчас перепроверил, размер n6 получается 1000 на 44. Но как мне, например, подавать на вход новую задачу, в n0[0][задача] или в n0[999][задача]? Ведь задача подаётся в виде одномерного массива, а не двухмерного массива, как в обучении.. И получение ответа, тоже не понятно, нужен одномерный массив.. Прошу прощения что туплю, в питоне и numpy пока не сильно разбираюсь..